# Automatically Restart WebApp after a phone call on an iPhone

Tags: iphone, iphone-web-app

I have an iPhone WebApp that is installed to the home page.  When a phone call comes in or an email is sent it brings up either the phone screen or the email screen.  After the user finishes the phone call or email, is it possible to automatically bring up the same web application that was previously open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Also native apps can't do this consistently (only for incoming, but not for outgoing calls the app will be launched again; e-mail can be sent from within the app).

Comment: Can email be sent from a WebApp or just a native app?  I can launch the email client, but that is a different behavior.

Comment: You can only launch the email client from a webapp AFAIK. Apple could change this behavior, but as a webapp you certainly don't and won't have any control over it.

Answer (score 1):

Kevin, yes it can be done with some effort. What you want is [HTML5 local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) and perhaps [HTML5 application caching](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html) as well.

What you do is not unlike what a pre-multitasking iPhone native app would do: you store the application state in the local storage and use it on launch to restore state. I don't believe you have hooks on termination so you'll have to store the state at every state transition, as it happens.